# If $|f(z)|\le |g(z^2)|$ for all $ z\in\mathbb{C} $, then $ f(z) =f(-z), \forall z\in\mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Consider two entire functions $f $ and $ g$. If $|f(z)|\le |g(z^2)|$ for all $ z\in\mathbb{C} $, show that $ f$ is even.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to solve this. This is a follow up question to this one: if $|f(z)|\le |g(z)|$ for all $ z\in\mathbb{C} $, then $ f=cg$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{C} $. I managed to solve this one, but I can't find a possible link between the two problems.

Could someone give a hint, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that, for some $c\in\mathbb C$, you have$$(\forall z\in\mathbb C):f(z)=cg(z^2).$$Therefore, if $z\in\mathbb C$,$$f(-z)=cg\bigl((-z)^2\bigr)=cg(z^2)=f(z).$$

Comment: Was it really that simple? Thank you a lot! My brain probably blocked when I saw the squared input for g...

Comment: Is it possible to solve this question without using the first problem?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The first statement follows from [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), so one could use that instead of the first problem (Liouville may have been how the first problem was answered).